# the Stone-Čech compactification by using ultrafilters

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

If $X$ is discrete, one can construct $\beta X$ as the set of all ultrafilters on $X$.

> But which **kind of topology** must we use in the above sentence?

How can we define the Stone–Čech compactification by using ultrafilters? What is the form of the topology in terms of ultrafilters?

Comment: Dear fatemeh : I took the liberty of adjusting your question a little. I hope you find the changes helpful.

Answer (score 4):

For each $A\subseteq X$ let $\widehat A=\{p\in\beta X:A\in p\}$; then $\{\widehat A:A\subseteq X\}$ is a base for the topology of $\beta X$. Note that if $x\in X$, then

$$\widehat{\{x\}}=\left\{p\in\beta X:\{x\}\in p\right\}=\{p_x\}$$

where $p_x$ is the principal ultrafilter over $x$: $p_x$ is an isolated point in $\beta X$. This is why we identify $p_x$ with $x$ and say that $X\subseteq\beta X$, when really it’s $\{p_x:x\in X\}$ that is the subset of $\beta X$ corresponding to $X$.

Comment: $p_ x$ is an isolated point in $β_X$?? for this reason, we say $\beta X$ is as a set of principal ultrafilters? if we consider $\omega$ with discrete topology, can we use mentioned topology for $\beta \omega$?

Comment: @fatemeh: No, $\beta X$ is the set of **all** ultrafilters on $X$, principal **and** non-principal. And yes, this is exactly the topology on $\beta\omega$.

Comment: when you say $ p \in \beta X $, is $p$ an ultrafilters on $X$? I mean the topology that you defined means the set of all ultrafilters that contain $A \subset X$? is this the same stone topology?

Comment: @fatemeh: Yes, I’m taking $\beta X$ here to be the set of all ultrafilters on $X$, so $p\in\beta X$ is an ultrafilter on $X$. And yes, if $A\subseteq X$, then the set of all ultrafilters on $X$ that contain $A$ is a basic open set in $\beta X$. This is the topology that it gets as the Stone space of the Boolean algebra $\wp(X)$ and as the Čech-Stone compactification of the discrete space $X$.