# Why $X$ is necessarily discrete?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

In the lecture, we introduced the Stone–Čech compactification via ultrafilters. More concretely, we defined $\beta X = \{\mathfrak{U}|\mathfrak{U}$ ultrafilter on $X\}$.

**This is possible for $X$ being a discrete set. I am wondering why this is necessary. What can cause troubles if X is not discrete/where is the discreteness needed so that βX is the space of ultrafilters?**

Intuitively, a discrete set is "small", ensuring that the map from $X \rightarrow \beta X$ is injective. We have proved that there are at least $2^{2^\kappa}$ ultrafilters for $\kappa$ being the cardinality of $X$, $\kappa ≥ \omega = |\mathbb{N}|$ but this should always be injective.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your asking for here. The Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$ is allowed to be large. It is bigger than $X$, and this poses no problem to there being an injection from $X$ into $\beta X$. Are you just surprised that it's so much larger than $X$? I was too, when I learned that $\beta \mathbb{N}$ is uncountable. But, if you consider that every continuous function (i.e. any function) on $\mathbb{N}$ has a continuous extension to $\beta \mathbb{N}$, you can glimpse at why so many new points need to be created.

Comment: @TheoBendit I am worried why the ultrafilterapproach requires $X$ to be discrete. Compactness is a property that is "close to finite", so i think discrete is used here to make a compactification meaningful (but then: this should be a property of the compactification itself), because the topology put on  $\beta X$ has principal ultrafilters as a basis. Why is that necessary for $X$?

Comment: So your question is "why $\beta X$ is the space of ultrafilters when $X$ is discrete"?

Comment: Well, I guess you could always point out one of the many infinite compact sets (naturally they cannot be discrete), and refer to the fact that the Stone-Cech compactification is homeomorphic to the set itself? I'm not familiar with the construction by ultrafilters, but I would guess that the ultrafilters produce a compact set that can be much larger than the Stone-Cech compactification.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My question is: "What can cause troubles if $X$ is not discrete/where is the discreteness needed so that $\beta X$ is the space of ultrafilters"

Comment: Then maybe it'd be great to just add this explicitly to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stone topology on $\beta X$ makes the principal ultrafilters $p_x$ isolated points for every $x \in X$, so if the canonical map $x \mapsto p_x$ is continuous (one of the properties of the Stone-Cech compactification), it forces $X$ to be discrete.

Comment: more information on that in another thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478469/the-stone-%C4%8Cech-compactification-by-using-ultrafilters